# Is it possible to use 'hostname' in inventory file as parameter 'url' in uri module?

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory file with a list of hostnames, in playbook file I have a task calling uri module. How do I pass the list of hostnames in webservers group to url in playbook and make the uri task loop through the hostnames in inventory file?

Not sure if it is doable. Or the only way is to put the hostnames in vars file?

inventory file

```
[webservers]
hostname1
hostname2
```

playbook file

```
- uri:
    url: http://[hostname1/hostname2]
    return_content: yes
  register: webpage
```

Comment: Are you going to have rwo host always? What happens if you have three or more?

Comment: just two hosts in my example. I will have more than 2 hosts, and the uri module in playbook need to loop all hosts, get the content from all hosts.

Comment: Read about [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below to iterate the hostnames in webserver group
- uri:
   url: http://{{ inventory_hostname }}/
   return_content: yes
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['webservers']
  register: webpage
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to iterate the uri task over the hosts of webserver group:

```
  - name: loop of uri module over the hosts group
    uri:
      url: http://{{ item }}/
      return_content: yes
    register: webpage
    with_items: 
      - "{{ groups['webserver'] }}"
```